# how to push a range of memory to the stack in asm?

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, stack, nasm

Is there an option to push a range of memory to the stack?

With `foo resd x` I can reserve x double words, whose addresses are consecutive.

Is there an option to push all the double words from address `foo` to address `foo+(4*x)` to the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the CPU and you haven't specified it (I'm guessing it's x86 because `resd` is nasm's way to reserve memory and nasm is x86 only).

There's no x86 instruction that can push an arbitrary number of `(d/q)words` on the stack. You can push several of them one by one in a loop. Or you can reserve space on the stack (by subtracting from `(e/r)sp`) and then copy the data using `mov` or `rep movsb/w/d/q`.

Comment: okay that's pity. I hoped thats something like this: `push DWORD*x foo` but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done by the assembler at compile time. Stack operations need to be done by the code at runtime.